# Protocol 'FlightRoutesDataProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Few days ago was trying to use an app with Xcode 10 and with Swift 4.2 which was earlier in Swift 4.1 but am not able to solve an error I am gettings while using 4.2 version of Swift.

**Having this protocol used in my application**

```
protocol MyProtocol: AnyObject, RealmCollectionValue {
var name: String { get }
var count: Int { get }

static func sortKeyPath() -> String

func getTitleText() -> String
func getValueText() -> String
func getCodeText() -> String?
func getSubtitleText() -> String?
}

extension MyProtocol {

static func sortKeyPath() -> String {
    return "count"
}

func getTitleText() -> String {
    return name
}

func getValueText() -> String {
    return "\(count)"
}

func getCodeText() -> String? {
    return nil
}

func getSubtitleText() -> String? {
    return nil
}
}
```

**The way it's used in the view model of my app**

```
private var data: [MyProtocol] = []
```

And it's giving me an error that.

**Protocol 'MyProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements**

Comment: `RealmCollectionValue` does this protocol contain associated values? there is plenty of results for this error on stackoverflow

Comment: Check https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-fix-the-error-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associated-type-requirements